# Como trocar o repositório local do meu projeto no Git

Tags: git

Eu estava desenvolvendo um projeto em um diretório no meu computador e coloquei ele no gitHub. Eu tive alguns problemas com o projeto e como tinha feito poucas coisas eu decidi começar novamente em outro diretório.

Usando o help do gitHub, usei o comando `git remote rm origin` pra remover a URL de remote do repositório, mas não deu certo, eu recebo a seguinte mensagem :

```
fatal: No such remote: 'URL DO REPOSITÓRIO'
```

Fiquei confuso com os comandos. Eu queria mudar o diretório do meu computador que alimenta o repositório do projeto no gitHub, e apagar oque tem nele atualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `git remote -v` para ver o que tem remoto.

Agora quero lhe deixar uma coisa bem clara, o `git remote rm ...` não remove do servidor do Github, ele simplesmente remove o `remote` e suas referências do **repositório local**.

Se deseja um novo diretório, você pode simplesmente apagar o atual local e fazer o clone novamente em outro lugar, agora se você já edições e afins o certo seria "commitar" e fazer o `push` pro remoto antes de mover de diretório local.

Só pra comentar, é possível ter diversos diretórios locais apontando para o mesmo remoto, sendo na mesma máquina (seu "computador") ou máquinas diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando a pergunta.

Se eu estiver trabalhando num projeto na pasta c:\Primeiro Projeto\ e quiser transferir tudo para c:\WORKSPACE\Primeiro Projeto\

Basta fazer um clone e deletar o antigo?

Comment: Se tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a clicando no botão [Fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Inclua um link para esta pergunta se ajudar a fornecer contexto. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/375791)